# C# to mysql - inserting new row to table with foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to insert a new row in a mysql table using C#.
The table looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyFpF.jpg), and contains one foreign key column. 
i use the follwing code to cinnect to the database and insert data.

```
    public virtual void addToDB()
    {
        try
        {
            //prepare for query
            var cmd = MySQL.readyQuery();

            //insert testdata to Vo2test
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vo2test_tb(ClientID, Weight, Methods, TimeOfDay, Date, StartResistance, Endresistance, TheoreticalMaxPulse, FatPercent3point, FatPercent7point, VO2_max, FitnessRating, HRmax, RERmax, TestTime, Raw_test_data) VALUES((SELECT UserID from user_tb WHERE UserID = '@UserID'), '@Weight', '@Method', '@Timeofday', '@Date', '@Startresistance', '@Endresistance', '@Theoreticalmaxpulse', '@Fatprocent3p', '@Fatprocent7p', '@vo2max', '@fitnessrating', '@hrmax', '@rermax', '@testtime', '@rawtestdata')";

            cmd.Prepare();
            //insert parameters som skal ændres: 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", Weight);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Method", Method);
            //coverts date to 0000-00-00
            string DateString = Convert.ToString(TestDate.Date.Date.Year) + "-" + Convert.ToString(TestDate.Date.Month) + "-" + Convert.ToString(TestDate.Date.Day);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateString);
            //converts time to 00:00:00. 
            string TimeString = Convert.ToString(TimeOfDay.Hour) + ":" + Convert.ToString(TimeOfDay.Minute) + ":00";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timeofday", TimeString);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Startresisstance", StartResistance);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Endressistance", EndResistance);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheoreticalMaxPulse", TheoreticMaxPulse);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatPercent3point", FatPercent3Point);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatPercent7point", FatPercent7Point);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VO2_max", Vo2Max);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FitnessRating", FitnessRating);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HRmax", HRmax);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RERmax", RERmax);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestTime", TimeOfDay);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raw_test_data", RawTestData);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

when i run it, i am told that ClientID can't be null but if i just run the sql query in Adminer it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure your sub select for the ClientID is correct. It doesnt looks correct where you are comparing the UserID against the FIrstName and returning the UserID

Comment: Have you tried by replacing the "@" by "?" ? "@" are for SQLServer

Comment: @MarrowGnawer It is @ in MySQL

Comment: `WHERE FirstName = '@UserID'` is this right comparison in sub query??

Comment: remove the quotes around the parameters in the query string. (eg `'@testtime'` should be just `@testtime`)

Comment: @nl-x okay, will do that. but can this actually cause a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub select in your insert query doesnt make sense. Why are you doing a sub select to insert a value you already have.

```
SELECT UserID from user_tb WHERE UserID = '@UserID'
```

Just insert @UserID directly.

Also you have wrapped all your @ parameters in single quotes in the query string. You do not need this. Parameterization deals with the quotes for you in the background. Remove all single quotes so that it just reads:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vo2test_tb(ClientID, Weight, Methods, TimeOfDay, Date, 
StartResistance, Endresistance, TheoreticalMaxPulse, FatPercent3point, FatPercent7point, 
VO2_max, FitnessRating, HRmax, RERmax, TestTime, Raw_test_data) 

VALUES((SELECT ClientID from user_tb WHERE UserID = @UserID), @Weight, @Method, @Timeofday, 
@Date, @Startresistance, @Endresistance, @Theoreticalmaxpulse, @Fatprocent3p, @Fatprocent7p, 
@vo2max, @fitnessrating, @hrmax, @rermax, @testtime, @rawtestdata)";
```

Comment: sorry, the Firstname = was just a test, I forget to change.
I changed i in the code and it is now
SELECT UserID from user_tb WHERE UserID = '@UserID'

I am still having the samem problem though.

Comment: @R0ede Your edit is still returning the UserID in the sub query. Shouldnt it be returning the ClientID.

Comment: UserID and ClientiD is actually the same. I have a table called user_tb, with different kind of users, one of them being clients. The clientID is a foreign key from the user_tb table where it is called UserID.

Comment: @R0ede If the UserID is the ClientID then why are you doing a sub select. Why not just insert "@UserID" directly into the ClientID?

Comment: as I understand I can't do this because it's a foreign key, and i need to tell it from which row in user_tb to get the foreign key. is there a better way?
bear with me, i'm a rookie.

Comment: @R0ede No, you're just inserting a value. If it is setup as a foreign key the MySql system will validate it itself.